# Find pattern of the file, create a folder with that pattern and copy the files to that folder - Bash script

Tags: linux, bash, file, copy

I have a task, to find the pattern of the file, create a folder with the pattern name and copy the file to that folder. I am able to create the folders.

---

```
folders=`find /Location -type f -name "*.pdf" -printf "%f\n" | cut -f 1 -d '_' | sort -u`
for i in $folders
do
    mkdir -p /LocationToCreateTheFolder/$i
done
```

---

Not able to go further on how to copy the files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe try?

```
for i in $folders do mkdir -p /LocationToCreateTheFolder/$i && cp ./$i.pdf ./$i/
```

Comment: Thanks worked, Task accomplished. Is there a way that we can copy one by one. For eg. if the find command finds Notice1_1.pdf, Notice2_1.pdf, Notice3_1.pdf, Notice2_2.pdf, Notice1_2.pdf..., first it should create Notice1, Notice2, Notice3 folders, then in the for loop the process should go this way, copy Notice1_1.pdf to Notice1 folder, then copy Notice2_1.pdf to Notices2 folder, then Notice3_1.pdf to Notice3 folder, then Notice2_2.pdf to Notice2 folder, then Notice1_2.pdf to Notice1 folder, instead of copying all Notice1_*.pdf to Notice1 folder and ....

Answer (score 0):

This will do the finding and the copying:

```
find Location -type f -name '*.pdf' -exec bash -c 'f=${1##*/}; d="LocationToCreateTheFolder/${f%%_*}"; mkdir -p "$d" && cp "$1" "$d"' None {} \;
```

This is safe for difficult file names even ones that contain spaces, tabs, or newlines in their names.

#### How it works

- `find Location -type f -name '*.pdf' -exec bash -c '...'` None {} \;

  This will find the pdf files under directory `Location` and, for each one found, the bash commands inside `'...'` will be executed with `$1` set to the name of the file found.  (`$0` is set to `None`.  We don't use `$0`.)
- `f=${1##*/}`

  This removes the directory names from the name of the file.  This is an example of *prefix removal*: everything in `$1` up to and including the last `/` is removed.
- `d="LocationToCreateTheFolder/${f%%_*}"`

  This creates the name of the directory to which we want to send the file.

  `${f%%_*}"` is an example of *suffix removal*.  Everything in `$f` from the first `_` and after is removed.
- `mkdir -p "$d" && cp "$1" "$d"`

  This makes sure that the directory exists and then copies the file to it.